# Sorting array that holds dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I am making a small game in the sake of learning.

I want to sort a mutable array and for that i saw a few examples on line. The issue is, I need to sort an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary holds a name of a player, the time that took him to finish and the number of moves he used.

Is it possible to sort the dictionaries inside my major array?

If it is I would appreciate an explanation.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the spec for NSArray.  There is a whole flock of sort functions, at least half of which can be made to do what you want.

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast answer to your question is yes you can sort an array of dictionaries and I will show you how in a moment. But before that allow me to say that I don't recommend this. Based on what I understood from your explanation above each player has 3 characteristics: Name, Time, Counter. In such a case I don't see the need of an array of dictionaries, I see that you either have a dictionary of arrays where each array has the 3 items that you want, or you can create an object for your player (more recommended) and you will end up with an array of objects, which is the simplest, and then you will sort your objects easily...

To answer your question, one way is to use the method `sortedArrayUsingFunction` of `NSArray` where you can call it to ask for a custom sorting function like this:

```
mySortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:myCustomSort context:nil];
```

Now you can write your own sorting function where you will cast your object as needed. Here is an example:

```
NSInteger myCustomSort(id val1, id val2, void *context)
{
    NSDictionarry *dic1 = (NSDictionarry *) val1;
    NSDictionarry *dic2 = (NSDictionarry *) val2;
    //now you have 2 dictionaries from the array, jut do the comparison you want and return any of NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedDescending, or NSOrderedSame
}
```

Comment: If you look closely, an array of dictionaries is just fine. It's better from the point of encapsulation.

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the project and complexity later on, maybe if it is just a small project as he is saying dictionaries are fine, but it is good to have an idea on different approaches.

Comment: Hmmm… I'm not really sure how to use the code in the function you gave me. I understand it returns a NSInteger, but what exactly does val1 and val2 represent? And how does context help me?

Comment: val1 and val2 are automatically sent from `sortedArrayUsingFunction` and they represent 2 items from your array. Since we know that your array contains dictionaries we had to cast val1 and val2 to dictionaries inside the function. So dic1 and dic2 (in the function) will become the 2 dictionaries currently at test, you retrieve from them the name or score and compare... You don't need `context` therefore we sent `nil` to it. This is used if you need to send another object to the function, like if you are sorting the array with respect to another array.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can, but you have to provide the comparator block, something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [startArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString* aa = [a objectForKey:KEY_USERNAME];
    NSString* bb = [b objectForKey:KEY_USERNAME];
    return [bb compare:aa];
}];
```

This create a new (unmutable) array from "startArray" that is an array of dictionaries with the "KEY_USERNAME" key used to compare 2 arbitrary elements.